# Able to pull acr images but unable to check manifest

Tags: docker, acr

I want help in understanding how docker pull works for acr images. I have a private acr repository.

So i run `az acr login -n <repo> --expose-token --output tsv --query accessToken` to print out the access token.

Then i use this access token to login through docker: `docker login <repo>.azureacr.io --username 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 --password '<ACCESS TOKEN>'`. The login works.

Then i try pulling the docker image: `docker pull <image>:<tag>` which works, but when i do `docker manifest inspect <image>:<tag>` it fails with the following exception:

```
errors:
denied: requested access to the resource is denied   
unauthorized: authentication required
```

Questions:

1. How do i check what permissions I have/need to run these docker commands?
2. If docker pull is working is it wrong to assume docker manisfest inspect will also work? I mean docker somehow needs to check if the image with the tag exists before pulling it right?

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody is stumbling over this unanswered question like I did when I was looking for a solution.

It seems to me like the issue is with `docker manifest inspect` itself.
Like stated in the question, I also was able to pull from a private container registry, but the command for inspecting the manifest failed.

In [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/45779#discussioncomment-4817885), an alternative command was mentioned that worked for me with a container image on a private Gitlab Container Registry:

`docker buildx imagetools inspect`

It should provide more or less the same output.

The official documentation of the command can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_imagetools_inspect/).